# How to scrollTo an element according to an id using ScrollView?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, react-native-ios

I want to scrollTo the top with the reference to the id initially for a given list of items, hence I write the following code -

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import NotExpandedVaccineComponent from '../../../../components/Home/NotExpandedVaccineComponent';
import ExpandedVaccineComponent from '../../../../components/Home/ExpandedVaccineComponent';
import {ROOT} from '../../../../services/ApiUrl';
export default function VaccinationListScreen(props) {
  const {navigation} = props;
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [changedstatus, setChangedStatus] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setisLoading] = useState(true);
  const scrollRef = useRef(null);
  let id = props.route.params.id;
  let interbalIdArr;
  const childdob = props.route.params?.childdob;
  const selectedid = props.route.params?.selectedid;

  const [expand, setExpand] = useState({});
  let vaccinenameselected = props.route.params?.vaccineitem;
  console.log('vaccine selected', vaccinenameselected);
  const changevaccinestatus = (value) => {
    setChangedStatus(value);
  };
  const handleClickOnYourElem = (y) =>
    scrollRef.current.ScrollTo({y, animated: true});
  const getData = () => {
    let url = `${ROOT}/children/${id}/vaccinations`;

    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        setData(res.data.content);
        setisLoading(false);
        const items = res.data.content;
        items.map((a) => {
          const arr = a.vaccine_list.map((a) => a.vaccineInternalId);
          console.log('arr', arr);
          if (arr.includes(selectedid)) {
            console.log('jj', a.id);
            setExpand({[a.id]: true});
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    selectedid && handleClickOnYourElem(selectedid);
  }, [changedstatus, loading]);

  function handleOnPress(id, item) {
    setExpand((prev) => {
      let toggleId = true;

      if (prev[id]) {
        toggleId = {[id]: false};
      } else {
        toggleId = {[id]: true};
      }

      return {...toggleId};
    });
  }
  if (data == '' || loading == true) {
    return (
      <ActivityIndicator
        color="#FF1493"
        size="large"
        style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}
      />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView horizontal pagingEnabled ref={scrollRef}>
          {data != '' &&
            data !== undefined &&
            data !== null &&
            data.map((item) => {
              const selected = item.vaccine_list
                .map((a) => a.vaccineInternalId)
                .includes(selectedid);
              return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  key={item.id}
                  style={{
                    paddingLeft: 10,
                    paddingRight: 10,
                  }}
                  onPress={() => handleOnPress(item.id, item)}>
                  {expand[item.id] ? (
                    <ExpandedVaccineComponent
                      item={item}
                      id={id}
                      navigation={navigation}
                      changevaccinestatus={changevaccinestatus}
                      childdob={childdob}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <NotExpandedVaccineComponent item={item} />
                  )}
                </TouchableOpacity>
              );
            })}
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

But when I execute the same I get null is not an object(evaluating 'scrollRef.current.scrollTo') .

Why is that so?
Could anyone please point out where have I gone wrong?
Have been stuck since long kindly help me out.
Any leads would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on edited post, this should be changed:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    selectedid && handleClickOnYourElem(selectedid);
  }, [changedstatus, loading, selectedid]); // need "selectedid" as dependency
```

// Below are old contents, ignore

Try these

```
const vaccineRef = useRef(null);

ref={vaccineRef}

React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
  vaccineRef.current.scrollTo(selectedid);
}, [selectedid]);
```

Comment: you want me to add the useLayoutEffect inside useEffect?

Comment: Nope, I was suggesting to replace several lines and add an extra `useLayoutEffect`. Sorry for the unclear answer. Updated and hope it helps.

Comment: where should I use the useLayoutEffect? Do I need it?

Comment: It is throwing scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo is not a function, why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

it seems you forget `current`.

You need to use it like this:

```
...
const scrollRef = useRef();

const handleClickOnYourElem = y =>scrollRef.current.ScrollTo({y,animated: true});
  
return (
  <ScrollView ref={scrollRef} >
...
```

And this is not related to your Q but instead of

```
          {data != '' &&
            data !== undefined &&
            data !== null &&
            data.map((item) => {
```

You can simply use: `data?.map((item=> ...`

And doesn't need to make additional array for checking selected:

You can replace this:

```
              const selected = item.vaccine_list
                .map((a) => a.vaccineInternalId)
                .includes(selectedid);
```

with:

```
  const selected = (item.vaccine_list.find(({vaccineInternalId})=>vaccineInternalId===selectedid))?.vaccineInternalId
```

Comment: I am getting null is not an object (evaluating 'scrollRef.current.ScrollTo')

Comment: try ```const scrollRef = useRef();``` and see what's happen

Comment: still getting the same bug

Comment: delete the <SafeArea...> and check